# How to use multiple conditional in jquery? Use both IF OR in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying IF with OR in jquery but only "Returns" is working. "In Process" is not working. Help needed.

```
$('.target').change(function() {
     if (($(this).find('option:selected').val() == 'Returns') || ($(this).find('option:selected').val() == 'In Process')) {
       $(".answer").show('slow');
     }
     else{
         $(".answer").hide('slow');
     }
   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.val()` to get the selected value of a `select` element. Have a look below, it's working perfectly fine

```js
$('.target').change(function() {
     if ($(this).val() == 'Returns' || $(this).val() == 'In Process') {
       $(".answer").show('slow');
     }
     else{
         $(".answer").hide('slow');
     }
   });
```

```css
.answer{
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid #333;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="target">
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option value="Returns">Returns</option>
  <option value="In Process">In Process</option>
</select>
<br>
<div class="answer"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks #jonju Working Properly.

Comment: While this is a better way to write it, it doesn't explain why his original code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of all correct values and if selected value exists in array, show answer else hide.

You can also use `.toggle(expression)` to control visibility.

#### Sample:

```js
$('.target').change(function() {
  var valid = ["Returns", "In Process"];
  var value = $('option:selected', this).val().trim();
  $(".answer").toggle(valid.indexOf(value) > -1)
});
```

```css
.answer {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="target">
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option value="Returns">Returns</option>
  <option value="In Process">In Process</option>
</select>
<br>
<div class="answer">Answer</div>
```